# Accessing controls of a user control inside a child user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have an aspx page with a usercontrol say UC1. UC1 is using another usercontrol say UC1.1 and other controls like dropodown, date picker, cute editor etc. I want to get conrols of UC1 in the button click of UC1.1. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `UC1.1` we can get the usercontrol `UC1`. Gave these code in `UC1.1`:

```
Dim p As Page = HttpContext.Current.Handler
Dim ctrl1 As UserControl = p.FindControl("UC1")
Dim ddlStatus As DropDownList = ctrl1.FindControl("ddlStatus")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access parent controls using control collection from the parent.
Parent.Findcontrol(id)